# Excel Help: To return the row number that has the greatest row sum

Tags: microsoft-excel

How do you return the row number that has the greatest row sum. For e.g.

[image]

should return "6". Thanks

Comment: Please note that [SU] is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: There's probably a way to get fancy and do this in one formula, but that would require brain cells on coffee.  Simple solution: add a helper column with the row totals.

Comment: I am sorry that I forgot to mention that helper cells were not allowed. Also forgot to include the scripts/codes as mentioned by DavidPostill (Point taken). Thanks everybody esp. XOR LX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that data is in `A1:G10`, **array formula****:

`=MATCH(1,0/FREQUENCY(0,1/MMULT(A1:G10,TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(A1:G10)^0))))`

Regards

***Array formulas are not entered in the same way as 'standard' formulas. Instead of pressing just ENTER, you first hold down CTRL and SHIFT, and only then press ENTER. If you've done it correctly, you'll notice Excel puts curly brackets {} around the formula (though do not attempt to manually insert these yourself).*

Answer (score 1):

You can use this formula in a column next to your data, but you have to drag till the end row of your Data
`=IF(SUM(A1:G1)=MAX(SUM($A$1:$G$1),SUM($A$2:$G$2),SUM($A$3:$G$3),SUM($A$4:$G$4),SUM($A$5:$G$5),SUM($A$6:$G$6),SUM($A$7:$G$7),SUM($A$8:$G$8),SUM($A$9:$G$9),SUM($A$10:$G$10)),ROW(),"")`

[image]
It will give you the number of the row and all other cells will be empty.
**Another Easier Method**
Maybe having a helper row to sum each row then use match to identify the row of maximum is easier.
Create a new column to sum each row: `Sum(A1:G1)` and drag it down for each row.
under this column write the following formula and you will have the number of row where the sum = max
`=MATCH(MAX(H1:H10),H1:H10,0)`

[image]